# Storing current timestamp value in timestamp column in S3 for each line in the file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to store current timestamp in a field in the s3 file. So s3 file should have this field and value of current timestamp whenever that file is loaded to s3.
How do I do that and I want to generate this field in timezone local to s3. Is there a neat way to do this?
What I am thinking is that I will have this field in my local file and through java I will add this value to the local file in utc timezone? and whenever this file is loaded it will have that value generated by java code. but is there a better way to do this? and does s3 have a concept of timezone?

I tried to search on google but not able to come up with a better solution than this

Comment: but in this manner I will not be able to have the value of the timestamp when the file was uploaded rather it will be the value when I created that file in my local.

Comment: When a file is uploaded to a storage service like Amazon S3, the object will contain the contents of the file exactly as it was uploaded. The contents will not be modified. Amazon S3 automatically keeps track of the Created/Modified date of the object, so you can obtain this information about the object, but it will not be stored 'inside' the object itself.